# Android browsers blocking Youtube preroll ads natively

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, android, youtube

I was wondering if anyone else noticed that Youtube preroll ads are automatically blocked when browsing on Android Chrome or Android Firefox.  This is **without** any adblocking features enabled (no Adblock Plus installed, no Adblock installed in Firefox, no Firefox tracking protection enabled, etc.).  I'm not complaining by any means, because I do everything I can to block ads, but I was wondering if anyone knew why this happens (I'm curious from a technical/networking standpoint).

Comment: This would be better asked over at [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com), as it's not really [on topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here. The first one is that YouTube doesn't want to eat up all your bandwidth while you're on your phone. The second is that the ad is not targeted towards people on mobile. But this is just speculation. Either way it has to do with the mobile platform I'm sure.